# Get the selected option value of dropdown in last column of row in html table Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with 30 columns or so and I want to get the selected option for the dropdown that appears in each row. I have the below currently, but it returns null or undefined.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Invite Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="invitees">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
    <td><select class="form-control"><option value="Invitee" selected="selected">Invitee</option><option value="Alternate">Alternate</option></select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
    <td><select class="form-control"><option value="Invitee" selected="selected">Invitee</option><option value="Alternate">Alternate</option></select></td>
  </tr>

  <!-- and so on ... Built Dynamically -->

</tbody>
```

```
$('#invitees tr').each(function () {
    invite_statuses += $('td:last select').find('option:selected').val() + ",";
})
```

or

```
$('#invitees tr').each(function () {
    invite_statuses += $('td:last select').find('option:selected').text() + ",";
})
```

Am I missing something obvious or can this just not be done? It seems like this should work...

Comment: can you share the html ?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath Sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly refer the select box. The following solution gives selected items from each select box. check the console value.

```js
var rst="";
$('select').each(function () {
    rst+=$(this).find('option:selected').text()+" ";
});
console.log(rst);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Invite Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
    <td><select class="form-control"><option value="Invitee" selected="selected">Invitee</option><option value="Alternate">Alternate</option></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
    <td><select class="form-control"><option value="Invitee" >Invitee</option><option selected="selected" value="Alternate">Alternate</option></td>
  </tr>

  <!-- and so on ... Built Dynamically -->

</tbody>
```

Comment: I did not think of this approach! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `table` is missing the id(#) selector of "invitees". Once you have that, you can then loop through the table rows, get the last `td` select value, push that to an array, and then join it into a comma delimited list. Also, you are missing the closing `</select>` on your selects.

```js
var invite_statuses = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#invitees tbody tr').each(function() {
    var selection = $(this).find('td:last option:selected').val();
    console.log(selection);
    invite_statuses.push(selection);
  });

  console.log(invite_statuses.join(','));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="invitees" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Invite Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
      <option value="Alternate">Alternate</option>
      <option value="Invitee" selected="selected">Invitee</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
      <option value="Alternate" selected="selected">Alternate</option>
      <option value="Invitee" >Invitee</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- and so on ... Built Dynamically -->

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch on my missing closing tag, but I do not want an Id because that would require generating a unique Id for every drop-down and when looping through. After fixing my missing tag, results are the same.

Comment: Your table is missing the ID selector, not the select tags. Your original JS code referenced #invitees tr, which indicates that your table was using id #invitees, unless I am missing something.

Comment: You're right, sorry. This was a copy and paste error... it does exist. I will add it to the question's code.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure was referencing your complete code. The above answer works just as great as well!